# how to divide this form into two form, one for update one for store, without repeating unecessary code

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

I have a page to edit the administrators of a post. In this page it is possible to update the administrators of a post but also create new administrators for the post.

In this page there are some radio buttons. Each radio button corresponds to an administrator of a post. When a radio button is selected the details of that administrator are populated in the form fields. There is also a radio button "Create new admin" that when is selected the form fields reset so the user can insert values to create a new admin.

In this  page I have the form below that allows both update and also create a new admin based on the radio button selection. If the radio button selected is "Create new admin" the fields are reset so the user can insert a new admin. If other radio button is selected appears in the form fields the details of the selected administrator.

**Doubt:**

I have some JS that changes the action of the form based on radio button selection, but Im getting some issues with this approach so Im trying to divide the code below into two different forms instead of just only one form.

So I want one form for update and another to store a admin. When the page is acessed no form should be presented, only the radio buttons. And then when a user selects an administration through the radio button the update form should be presented. If the user selects the "Create new admin" radio button the store form should be presented and the update form hide if its visible.

But Im with some doubts about how to do this properly, how this can be done properly so is possible to reuse some code. For example dont seems correct to repeat twice this code:

```
@foreach($administrators $admin)
   <div class="form-check">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="radiobutton" id="{{$admin->id}}" value="">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="">
       {{$admin->name}}
      </label>
   </div>
 @endforeach
```

**Form for both update and create:**

```
 <form method="post" class="clearfix" action="{{route('admins.update', ['id' => $post->id])}}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {{csrf_field()}}
        @foreach($administrators $admin)
              <div class="form-check">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="radiobutton" id="{{$admin->id}}" value="">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="">
                  {{$admin->name}}
                </label>
              </div>
        @endforeach

 <div class="form-check">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="radiobutton" id="create_administrator"
                 value="option2">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios2">
              Create new administrator
          </label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" required class="form-control" value="{{ $admin->name }}" name="name">
      </div>

      <!-- below I have more form fields like administrator name, email, etc -->

      <input type="submit" id="adminStoreButton" class="btn btn-primary" value="Create"/>
      <input type="submit" id="adminUpdateButton" class="btn btn-primary" value="Update"/>
      </form>
```

**Js for this logic above:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        $("#adminStoreButton").hide();

        var admins = {!!  $admin !!}

        $("input[name='radiobutton']").click(function() {

            if($(this).attr("id") == "create_administrator"){
                $("#adminUpdateButton").hide();
                $("#adminStoreButton").show();
                $("#edit_administrator").attr('action', '{{route('admins.store', ['post_id' => $post->id])}}');
            }
            else{
                $("#adminUpdateButton").show();
                $("#adminStoreButton").hide();
                $("#edit_administrator").attr('action', '{{route('admins.update', ['post_id' => $post->id])}}');

            }

            let id = $(this).attr("id");
            let data = admins.find(e => e.id == id) || {
                name: "",
                email: "",
                ...
            };

            $("input[name='name']").val(data.name);
            $("input[name='email']").val(data.email);
           ...            
        });
    });
```

Comment: As a matter of "pattern", I make the form _the same_ for add / edit, and vary my logic for saving / updating depending on whether it's new / update.

Comment: Offtopic, make your HTML more valid... `label class="form-check-label"  for="{{$admin->id}}"` :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand well you want to "divide the code below into two different forms instead of just only one form".

Normally I would recommend using the [Laravel-Collective](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/master/html) Form class, which comes with **Form::open** and **Form::model** (for Form Model Binding).

Using this two methods with **Blade Template Engine** instruction [@include](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/blade#including-sub-views), you can write one partial block and re-use it always you want, just create a partial file (e.g. form-body.blade.php) with the body of the form (the parts between open "form" tag and "input type='submit'").

Note that the two (Collective Form and Blade) do not need to be used together, you can use only one of them if you prefer or both together (I recommend both to maximize the writing speed of code).

Something like:

```
    {!! Form::open(['url' => 'foo/bar', 'method' => 'put']) !!}
    @include('form-body.blade.php')
    {!! Form::submit('Save') !!}
    {!! Form::close() !!}
```

Or

```
    {!! Form::model($user, ['route' => ['user.update', $user->id]]) !!}
    @include('form-body.blade.php')
    {!! Form::submit('Update') !!}
    {!! Form::close() !!}
```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

- Use the same form.
- The form should contain a hidden field `id`
- On the controller logic:

  - if the id is set, update the corresponding row.
  - if the id is empty, create a new row.

Answer (score 0):

I would solve that server side

```
<?php
if( $_POST['radiobutton'] == 'value2' ) {
   // create
}
else {
   // update
}
?>
```